# Subsetting postcode ranges

Tags: r

I am trying to subset my data frame using a selection of postcodes. I'm unsure what is wrong with the code I wrote:

So the ranges of postcodes are: 6000-6199 & 6800-6999 (the postcodes are integers)

```
df1 <- subset(df, ((df$postcode>=6000 && df$postcode<=6199) | (df$postcode>=6800 && df$postcode<=6999)))
```

This is the error that I get:

> Error: unexpected symbol in:
>   "df1<-subset(df, (df$postcode>=6000 & df$postcode<=6199 | (df$postcode>=6800 & df$postcode<=6999))
>   df1"

Perhaps there is a way to write this using a vector of postcodes?

I also tried:

```
df1<-subset(df, (df$postcode in [6000:6199] | df$postcode in [6800:6999]))
```

but it returns this error message:

> Error: unexpected 'in' in "df1<-subset(df, (df$postcode in"` which makes me think I can't use the term "in".

I'm sure the solution is simple but I'm unable to figure it out.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You need single `&` instead of `&&` In the second case, it would be `subset(df, (postcode %in% c(6000:6199, 6800:6999)))`

Comment: @akrun ...I can't believe I didn't try that out. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

In the first case, it may be `&` instead of `&&`

```
subset(df, ((postcode>=6000 & postcode<=6199) | (postcode>=6800 & postcode<=6999)))
```

and in second

```
subset(df, (postcode %in% c(6000:6199, 6800:6999)))
```

NOTE: Within the `subset`, the `df$` is not needed to extract the columns